# Como uso las funciones de un menu de una bibliotecas de google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de apps script para una hoja de calculo ,este lo voy a compartir con unas pocas personas asi que la manera mas sencilla que se me ocurrió de compartirselos y poder mantener el código fue mediante bibliotecas .
El código original tiene  las funciones que  llamo mediante un menu:

```
 function crearMenu(){
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('  Nuevas funciones')
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Primer subMenu')
      .addItem('Funcion A', 'funcionA'))
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Segundo subMenu')
      .addItem('Funcion B', 'funcionB')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Funcion C', 'funcionC')
      .addSeparator())
    .addToUi();

}
```

hasta ahora todo bien, importe la libreria como ***testLibreria***

Tanto en esta nuevo projecto y el original estoy llamando a la funcion `crearMenu()` desde un activdor simple `onOpen(e)`

```
function onOpen(e){
testLibreria.crearMenu();
}
```

Mi problema es que no encuentro como  llamar correctamente las funciones que utiliza el menu en las nuevas hojas. Cuando intente correr las funciones desde el menu en la nueva hoja pero arroja el error de que no las encuetra.

Lo primero que intente fue poner los metodos ahi en el proyecto:

```
     testLibreria.funcionA();
  testLibreria.funcionB();
  testLibreria.funcionC();
```

Volví a intentar correrlo pero se ejecutaban todas las funciones al mismo tiempo.
Otra cosa que intente fue englobar todas las funciones en una funcion ahi mismo pero tampoco tengo idea de como podria llamarlo desde el menu.

Alguna ayuda de como podría hacerlo, estoy bastante perdido ya que es la primera vez que uso bibliotecas.

Answer (score 0):

He estado investigando y al parecer no se puede.

Lo que tuve que hacer para poder usar las funciones de la bibloteca fue : copiar el menu del codigo original y pegarlo a las nuevas hojas , y añadir el identificador de la libreria a las funciones del menu.

```
function crearMenuLibrerias(){
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('  Nuevas funciones')
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Primer subMenu')
      .addItem('Funcion A', 'testLibreria.funcionA'))
    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Segundo subMenu')
      .addItem('Funcion B', 'testeLibreria.funcionB')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Funcion C', 'testLibreria.funcionC')
      .addSeparator())
    .addToUi();

}
```

Así si pude asignar correctamente cada función a cada opción del menu. El único inconveniente es que si agrego mas opciones al menú, tendré que ir a cada código a actualizar cada menu uno por uno....